# Creating namedtuple valid for differents parameters

Tags: python, python-3.7, namedtuple

I'm trying to figure it out a way to create a **namedtuple with variable fields depending on the data you receive**, in my case, I'm using the data from [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser) and not on all the periods are the same browsers. I tried this way but it is a bit ugly and I'm sure there is a better way to achieve it.

```py
def namedtuple_fixed(name: str, fields: List[str]) -> namedtuple:
    """Check the fields of the namedtuple and changes the invalid ones."""

    fields_fixed: List[str] = []

    for field in fields:
        field = field.replace(" ", "_")

        if field[0].isdigit():
            field = f"n{field}"

        fields_fixed.append(field)

    return namedtuple(name, fields_fixed)


Records: namedtuple = namedtuple("empty_namedtuple", "")


def read_file(file: str) -> List["Records"]:
    """
    Read the file with info about the percentage of use of various browsers
    """
    global Records

    with open(file, encoding="UTF-8") as browsers_file:
        reader: Iterator[List[str]] = csv.reader(browsers_file)
        field_names: List[str] = next(reader)
        Records = namedtuple_fixed("Record", field_names)
        result: List[Records] = [
            Records(
                *[
                    dt.datetime.strptime(n, "%Y-%m").date()
                    if record.index(n) == 0
                    else float(n)
                    for n in record
                ]
            )
            for record in reader
        ]
    return result
```

The "namedtuple_fixed" function is to fix the names that have invalid identifiers.

Basically, I want to create a named tuple that receives a **variable number of parameters**, depending on the file you want to analyze. And if it's with type checking incorporated (I mean using *NamedTuple* from the typing module), much better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a `dict` instead? Maybe converting it to `namedtuple` after you're done adding stuff to it?

Comment: Hi perhaps build first from a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem, but just partially

```py
class Record(SimpleNamespace):
    def __repr__(self):
        items = [f"{key}={value!r}" for key, value in self.__dict__.items()]
        return f"Record({', '.join(items)})"
```

Using the [types.SimpleSpace](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) documentation

And it can cause problems, like for example if you initiallize a Record like the following:

```py
foo = Record(**{"a": 1, "3a": 2})
print(foo.a) # Ok
print(foo.3a) # Syntax Error
```